# Windows Server 2008 - Give my ASP.NET website write permission to a folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, permissions, windows-server-2008

I have a folder "foo" which resides under the root folder of my ASP.NET website.

My ASP.NET website has a file browser control which enables (authenticated) users to upload files, create folders, move folders, delete file/folders etc. in the "foo" folder.

What permissions should the "foo" folder have?

It is a Windows Server 2008 / IIS 7 box.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the authentication method you are using, either the end user or the Application Pool Identity user will need Modify privileges to the foo folder.

**UPDATED**:
It sounds like you are using Anonymous Authentication, but are authenticating the user in your DB via your application.

Check your IIS to determine [which identity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) Anonymous Authentication is using. The default is IUSR, but you can also decide to use the application pool identity, in which case, you will need to check your Application Pool Identity.

If you have stuck with the defaults, you will likely only need to add Modify permissions to the built-in IUSR user.

Additional backround info: [Understanding Built-In User and Group Accounts in IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis/)

Comment: The authentication method is nothing special, it's just a username/password (lookup in DB) with a CAPTCHA, and then a session variable upon successful authentication. I'm trying to make it reasonably secure in terms of read/write permissions. Is Network Service the wrong account for this?

Comment: The ApplicationPoolIdentity is often recommended (see: http://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account), but Network Service is fine (and many other people use it in your circumstances)

Comment: Ok I shall look into that thanks. When I'm developing and running websites on my local machine with IIS, I often have to add read/execute permissions to the IUSR account (or sometimes IIS_IUSRS) on the root folder of my website. Are they not required on a Internet (IIS) web server?