# IIS 7.0 HTTP Error 403.14 & 404.3 while uploading with WebMatrix?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I am having an issue i get 2 IIS errors when accesing
domain.com and another when accessing domain.com/default.cshtml

I am trying to upload with WebMatrix.
I have no configuration in Webmatrix but making "starter site" from the page template.
When i upload it to my server and access.

Do i need to change something in server configurations or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable uploading files to your server, you need to make sure the permissions are set up properly.  The user account under which your app pool is running needs to have write permission to the directory where you're trying to upload files.  This is no different from configuring a normal ASP.NET application to have upload rights to IIS, so here's a good question to look at:

[Windows Server 2008 - Give my ASP.NET website write permission to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026819/windows-server-2008-give-my-asp-net-website-write-permission-to-a-folder)

Good luck!